# Need to find a minimal basis

Tags: database

I'm struggling with finding a minimal basis for the given relation and FD's. Can you please confirm I'm doing it right?

I've got R(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)

```
A -> G
E -> F,G
C,D -> B
B -> E
C,D -> A
```

After checking each FD there is nothing to remove, so my minimal basis is

```
A -> G
E -> F
E -> G
C,D -> B
B -> E
C,D -> A
```

and the key is (C,D) as (C,D)+ = (C,D,A,B,E,F,G)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In American English, I think the term is *minimal cover*.

CD is the only candidate key in R.

I'm not sure what you mean by "checking each FD", but your result is right.

Comment: Many thanks! By checking I meant if we can remove this FD or not to get a minimal basis/cover